# Using a function in another file to find a file's path/address in PHP

Tags: php, function, filepath, dirname

I have a PHP function in another file (with a bunch of other functions) that returns a file's address. Call the file commonFunctions.php. See below.

```
function filePath($fPath) {
    $cutPath = str_replace("/var/www","http://myinternalwebsite",$fPath);
    return $cutPath;
}
```

When I want another file's address, I just include my function file by using `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/commonFunctions.php` and call `filePath(dirname(__FILE__))`. The result is something like `http://myinternalwebsite.com/myScript.php`.

Is there a way to place `dirname(__FILE__)` inside of my function so all I have to do is reference the function by typing filePath()? I tried doing something like the following

```
function filePath() {
    $cutPath = str_replace("/var/www","http://myinternalwebsite",dirname(__FILE__));
    return $cutPath;
}
```

but that obviously gives me the address of the commonFunctions.php file and not the file that I am calling the function in.

Thanks in advance.

-Anthony

Comment: There is not a way to do what you are asking. If there is a more general problem you're trying to solve, perhaps stating that problem will spark someone to be able to comment on an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use something like this ?

`$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];`

This outputs the complete URL, with the file, as :

if URL is http://website.com/section/index.php
it returns `website.com/section/index.php`

if URL is http://website.com/section/
it returns `website.com/section/index.php`

I mean, as I understood it, you may not need a function.

Comment: I'm going with this. Thanks!